# Online SQL Database Connection Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am trying to connect my asp.net app to a database on smarterasp.net.

I am getting an error that throws me into my catch when the connection tries to open.  The error says it is network related, except I am not able to find out how to fix this.  If anybody has any ideas it would be greatly appreciated!

Here is my method:

```
// POST: api/User
        public void Post([FromBody]Person model)
        {
            const string myConnection = "Server=MYSQL5004.Smarterasp.net;Database=xxx;Uid=xxx;Pwd=xxx;";

            try
            {
                using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnection))
                {
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO tblUser (FirstName, LastName, Email, Username, Password) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Email, @Username, @Password)", connection)
                    {
                        CommandType = CommandType.Text,
                        Connection = connection
                    };

                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", model.FirstName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", model.LastName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Email", model.Email);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Username", model.UserName);
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Password", model.Password);

                    connection.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                var response = e.ToString();
            }

        }
```

Here is the exception that is being thrown:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"

Comment: Your error message is very clear.  The driver cannot find the sql server instance.  Is this a local instance or is `MYSQL5004.Smarterasp.net` somewhere on your network?  Additionally, the server is called `mysql` and you're trying to connect to a `sql server` instance.  Could that be part of the problem?

Comment: The database is hosted by the website smarterasp.net.

Comment: Then I would say you should contact them.  They need to open up ports in order to connect over tcp/ip.  They probably have a standard way of doing this, but it clearly doesnt match your current connection string.